# how to play a video url (url ending with .mp4 or .webm) in android webview

Tags: android-webview

I want to run a video url (url ending with .mp4 or .webm) in a android webview 
When I am using  webview.loadUrl("XXX.mp4")
the video is not playing
 please help with code snippet.